# SAP B1 using Unions and Where date selection

Tags: sql, sapb1

I need help on running the following query, the date selection does not work. What am I doing wrong? I want to run a "Sales register" with variable dates showing all sales and credits in one report - it needs to align with the total on the Sales analysis.

```
SELECT T0.[DocDate], T0.[DocNum], T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName],T0.[DocTotal], T0.[VatSum] FROM OINV T0

UNION ALL

SELECT T0.[DocNum], T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName], -1 * T0.[DocTotal], -1 * T0.[VatSum] FROM ORIN T0

WHERE T0.DocDate>='[%0]' and T0.DocDate<='[%1]'
```

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) You can use a *code block* to present a block of code: either put four (additional) blanks before each line, or mark the block and use the "code button" (`{}`) from the post editor tool bar. To cause a line-break, just append two blanks to the end of a line. Much more time is invested in reading posts than in typing them: A spelling checker would have pointed you to two `i` that should have been capital, and just type *one* - 140 byte SM are so 90s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you've given won't run at all - the subqueries have different numbers of columns in them. If you want to do a union, they must have the same number of columns and the same types.

Aside from that, you've got 2 subqueries - one from `OINV` and one from `ORIN`, and the date filter is only applied to the `ORIN` subquery.

Try this, it should fix those problems.

```
SELECT T0.[DocDate], T0.[DocNum], T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName],T0.[DocTotal], T0.[VatSum]
FROM OINV T0
WHERE T0.DocDate>='[%0]' and T0.DocDate<='[%1]'

UNION ALL

SELECT T0.[DocDate], T0.[DocNum], T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName], -1 * T0.[DocTotal], -1 * T0.[VatSum]
FROM ORIN T0
WHERE T0.DocDate>='[%0]' and T0.DocDate<='[%1]'
```

Comment: Can a third table be added, i.e. ORDR?

Comment: Absolutely! Just add another subquery `UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM ORDR T0 WHERE ...`

Comment: It's worth noting that using the same Alias (i.e. `T0`) in different subqueries is usually frowned upon for readability reasons, but it may be necessary in this case to get the date picker working properly in the query.

Comment: I just tried as suggested but the date picker did nothing, it simply picked up all records?